# How to target current focused element from array to call focusout function?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, events, focus

I'm trying to create a series of editable paragraphs that recieve focus and become editable after I click a button; after that I'm looking for a way to simply set its `contenteditable` attribute to `false` when the paragraph loses focus; I simply don't know and haven't found a clear way to target the specific paragraph that is focused to trigger the function when I'm dealing with an array of elements.

I'm sure there might be syntax errors or rules that I'm not following at all, I'm still practicing JavaScript so I don't know all the workings of the language. Any help is appreciated

**NOTE:** If there's a way to also avoid using the `onclick` HTML attribute and call the `editInfo` function only from JavaScript that would also be great

This is my code at the moment

```js
function editInfo(paragraph) {
  var editableparagraph = document.getElementById(paragraph)

  editableparagraph.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true')
  editableparagraph.focus();
}

var editableParagraph = document.getElementsByClassName('editable');
editableParagraph.onfocusout = function() {
  editableParagraph.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');
}
```

```html
<h4>About Me <button class="edit-btn" onclick="editInfo('about-me-p')">Edit</button></h4>

<p contenteditable="false" id="about-me-p" class="editable">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

<h4>About You<button class="edit-btn" onclick="editInfo('about-you-p')">Edit</button></h4>

<p contenteditable="false" id="about-you-p" class="editable">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
```

Comment: Do you need a button for every area or would just clicking on the area be ok with you? You could for example add a special class to areas that should be editable and then you can do a simple loop to add event listeners to all those elements. Would that be ok?

Comment: I'd prefer the button since its part of the design spec I was given, thus I'm building it like that; I'm just having a hard time figuring out the best way to trigger the `onfocusout` event when I'm dealing with an array; I can do it by specifying the position in the array like `editableParagraph[1].setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');` but of course this is not ideal

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've shared so far it sounds as if you have all the editable areas from a page inside an array already. Based off your comment it seems that this is an array with references to the actual `elements` and not just an array of their ID's. So here is my suggestion which does not use the buttons:

```
// Note you may not need to pass in the array like I did.
function addListeners( array ){

    // ADD CODE HERE FOR A FOR LOOP
    // LOOP THROUGH THE ARRAY OF ELEMENTS
    for(...){

    // For all major browsers, except IE 8 and earlier
    if ( array[x].addEventListener) {
        array[x].addEventListener("click", makeEditable);
        array[x].addEventListener("blur", removeEditable);

    // For IE 8 and earlier versions
    } else if (array[x].attachEvent) {
        array[x].attachEvent("onclick", makeEditable);
        array[x].attachEvent("onblur", removeEditable);
    }

    // END FOR LOOP
    }
}

// Call our function to add the listeners. Make sure the page is loaded first!
addListeners( arrayOfElements);

function makeEditable(){
   // ... Your code to make an area editable
}

function removeEditable(){
   // ... Your code to remove content editable
}
```

If the array you have is just the ID's of the elements you can make a for loop that loops through the array and does `document.getElementById( ... )` on each item in the array and then save the elements reference in the array instead of the ID.

You could do something very similar if you want/ need to keep the buttons. You can use the same or similar `addListeners` function I made to add listeners to the buttons that in turn runs the `makeEditable` function on the correct area. you would then need to add an `onblur` event listener at the same time that you made the area editable so it know to turn itself off when the user leaves it.

Hopefully this gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think I might have not explained well... See this images: https://imgur.com/a/yIFJrTp

The basic idea is just that, paragraph becomes editable when I click on the button, and reverts back to not editable if I click anywhere else. I actually solved it using a `forEach` loop to get all the paragraphs and just added a function on each paragraphs `onfocusout` event